# Normalization and multivalued attributes

Tags: mysql, normalization, relational-theory

I am designing a relational database in mySQL - a library management system. I want to show examples of the data in 1NF, 2NF, 3NF, BCNF, etc. My example of 1NF looks something like this

[image]
'A relation is in first normal form if the domain of each attribute contains only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain.'

I am unsure of if the data is in 1NF. As a book can be written by multiple authors, the attributes author_first_name, author_middle_name, and author_last_name are multivalued attributes. How should I take this into consideration in my example of 1NF?